# Hide shipping method price and display only shipping method title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Please refer to video reference link: “https://www.loom.com/share/e3fb59a2423545aca06f40ec864d7af1”

I have nearly 30 shipping methods at checkout based on areas and I need to show only shipping method title and hide its costs so user can see only overall total added to their delivery charges

unable target the price class id(to implement none property in CSS) to hide the price alone, as both are showing as same name class id's

I have also checked other plugins disabled like cartflows or shipping method display style but couldn't make it

Could you please check this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below javascript code because the price is not in separate class so we need to strip the string after  "**:**" . I've tested the script with your shipping methods & it works. Put script in footer of the page or footer of the website.

```js
  var x = document.getElementById("shipping_method_0");
  
  for(var i=0; i<=x.length-1; i++) {

    var opt = x.options[i];
    var opt_curr_label = opt.innerText;
    var opt_new = opt_curr_label.substr(0, opt_curr_label.lastIndexOf(":"));
    opt.label = opt_new;

  }
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <body>

    <select name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0" class="shipping_method">
                                        <option value="flat_rate:6" selected="selected">Select Your Area Ammanur: ₹40.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:7">Ambedkar Nagar: ₹25.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:43">Arakkonam State Highways: ₹25.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:8">Ashok Nagar: ₹30.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:9">Ganesh Nagar: ₹30.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:10">Gandhi Nagar: ₹30.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:11">Galivari Kandigai: ₹40.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:12">Jawahar Nagar In &amp; Out: ₹40.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:41">Jothi Nagar: ₹25.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:13">Kainoor Railway Gate Near: ₹35.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:14">Krishna Polytechnic Surrounding: ₹30.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:15">Kilkuppam: ₹50.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:16">Lakshmi Nagar: ₹30.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:17">Madhava Nagar: ₹30.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:18">Mangammapet: ₹35.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:93">Mangammapet outer: ₹40.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:19">Netaji Nagar: ₹40.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:20">Nehruji Nagar: ₹25.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:21">Nagaalamma Nagar: ₹40.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:22">Palanipet: ₹30.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:23">Palanipet (Outer): ₹35.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:24">Perumuchi: ₹50.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:25">Polur: ₹50.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:26">Puliyamangalam Railway Station (7am-5pm): ₹40.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:27">Rajaji Nagar: ₹25.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:28">Railway Hospital Circle: ₹30.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:42">SBI Surrounding: ₹35.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:29">Shah Nagar: ₹40.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:30">Sivasakthi Nagar Near: ₹40.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:31">SR Gate: ₹30.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:32">Stuartpet Circle: ₹25.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:33">Taluk Office Backside: ₹25.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:34">Thandalam: ₹50.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:35">Town Hall Streets: ₹25.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:36">TN Housing Board: ₹25.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:37">Upparapalayam: ₹35.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:38">Uppukulam surrounding: ₹25.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:39">Venkatesapuram: ₹40.00</option>
                                        <option value="flat_rate:40">Winterpet: ₹30.00</option>
                                </select>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes I have tried "https://www.loom.com/share/a0fec8e3b4e640048883d720af359163" but still not working

Comment: Can i see the website ?

Comment: Seems like website is restricted to only admins. if you make it live for few minutes I'll give you exact CSS code to hide price

Comment: hi could you please resize the browser to mobile screen by simply pressing restore button next to close button on top right corner of the browser to view the website. thanks

Comment: Updated answer please check

Comment: Note : the script should be within <script></script> Tag

Comment: hi I have tried pasting the given code in the footer of the theme and here ("https://www.loom.com/share/9053c2d06dc2470a9242aad6d78315ff") is the reference, am not sure whether the method of pasting the code is correct or not. Could you please check and advise. Thanks for your help

Comment: noooooo. You just need to add js code & not HTML code... I just added that code for your testing... Add only this......
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("shipping_method_0");
  
  for(var i=0; i<=x.length-1; i++) {

    var opt = x.options[i];
    var opt_curr_label = opt.innerText;
    var opt_new = opt_curr_label.substr(0, opt_curr_label.lastIndexOf(":"));
    opt.label = opt_new;

  } </script>

install this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers & Put the given script in footer section of plugin settings & remove everything from footer.php

Comment: hi I have removed everything which was done earlier and followed latest comment and am not sure why the issue remains, please refer this "https://www.loom.com/share/699fc5a39712490c9093a724e45890cb"

Comment: Hi, I can't see the website even in mobile. can you please give me access to inspect. If you reply ASAP I can look into it

Comment: the site will be working from 7am-3.30pm and 5pm to 8.30pm IST. could you please check and let me know

Comment: Hi, I don't see the given script is added in footer. Even I checked the script by putting directly in console & it's working fine - https://www.loom.com/share/41dd5ba8517b4a359124ecbb7fdbf106